# Requirement already satisfied: pynput

Tags: python, pip, pynput

I have a problem  I got such error after using this command

python -m pip install pynput

```
Requirement already satisfied: pynput in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.7.6) 
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pynput) (1.16.0)
```

Comment: seems not an error, it looks like pynput is already installed on site-packages path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer is telling you that the requirement is already satisfied, meaning that pynput is already on your device and is ready to use. Hope that helps out!